# How to add/mix texture.image to shadowMapping demo

Tags: webgpu

I use https://webgpu.github.io/webgpu-samples/

I wanna integrate simple texture to the https://webgpu.github.io/webgpu-samples/?sample=shadowMapping example.

loadTex (this.texture0)

```js
  async loadTex0(texturesPaths, device) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      const response = await fetch(texturesPaths[0]);
      const imageBitmap = await createImageBitmap(await response.blob());

      this.texture0 = device.createTexture({
        size: [imageBitmap.width, imageBitmap.height, 1],
        format: 'rgba8unorm',
        usage:
          GPUTextureUsage.TEXTURE_BINDING |
          GPUTextureUsage.COPY_DST |
          GPUTextureUsage.RENDER_ATTACHMENT,
      });
      var texture0 = this.texture0
      device.queue.copyExternalImageToTexture(
        {source: imageBitmap},
        {texture: texture0},
        [imageBitmap.width, imageBitmap.height]
      );
      resolve()
    })
  }
```

Fow begin i just put

```js
      this.sceneBindGroupForRender = this.device.createBindGroup({
        layout: this.bglForRender,
        entries: [
          {
            binding: 0,
            resource: {
              buffer: this.sceneUniformBuffer,
            },
          },
          {
            binding: 1,
            resource: this.shadowDepthTextureView,
          },
          {
            binding: 2,
            resource: this.device.createSampler({
              compare: 'less',
            }),
          }, // ADDED HERE
          {
            binding: 3,
            resource: this.texture0.createView(),
          },
        ],
      });
```

I need shaders also to be updated...
I not sure is it posible some inject intro `texture_depth_2d`:

```
@group(0) @binding(1) var shadowMap: texture_depth_2d;
@group(0) @binding(2) var shadowSampler: sampler_comparison;
```

OR i need to add new tec sample and texture and then in main func
to call something like `color.rgb += texture`

```
      this.sceneBindGroupForRender = this.device.createBindGroup({
        layout: this.bglForRender,
        entries: [
          {
            binding: 0,
            resource: {
              buffer: this.sceneUniformBuffer,
            },
          },
          {
            binding: 1,
            resource: this.shadowDepthTextureView,
          },
          {
            binding: 2,
            resource: this.device.createSampler({
              compare: 'less',
            }),
          },
 
          {
            binding: 3,
            resource: this.sampler,
          },
          {
            binding: 4,
            resource: texture.createView(),
          },

        ],
      });
```

```
export let fragmentWGSL = `override shadowDepthTextureSize: f32 = 1024.0;

struct Scene {
  lightViewProjMatrix : mat4x4f,
  cameraViewProjMatrix : mat4x4f,
  lightPos : vec3f,
}

@group(0) @binding(0) var<uniform> scene : Scene;
@group(0) @binding(1) var shadowMap: texture_depth_2d;
@group(0) @binding(2) var shadowSampler: sampler_comparison;

@group(0) @binding(3) var meshSampler: sampler;
@group(0) @binding(4) var meshTexture: texture_2d<f32>;

struct FragmentInput {
  @location(0) shadowPos : vec3f,
  @location(1) fragPos : vec3f,
  @location(2) fragNorm : vec3f,
}

const albedo = vec3f(0.9);
const ambientFactor = 0.2;

@fragment
fn main(input : FragmentInput) -> @location(0) vec4f {
  // Percentage-closer filtering. Sample texels in the region
  // to smooth the result.
  var visibility = 0.0;
  let oneOverShadowDepthTextureSize = 1.0 / shadowDepthTextureSize;
  for (var y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {
    for (var x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {
      let offset = vec2f(vec2(x, y)) * oneOverShadowDepthTextureSize;

      visibility += textureSampleCompare(
        shadowMap, shadowSampler,
        input.shadowPos.xy + offset, input.shadowPos.z - 0.007
      );
    }
  }
  visibility /= 9.0;

  let lambertFactor = max(dot(normalize(scene.lightPos - input.fragPos), normalize(input.fragNorm)), 0.0);
  let lightingFactor = min(ambientFactor + visibility * lambertFactor, 1.0);

  let textureColor = textureSample(meshTexture, meshSampler, input.shadowPos.xy);


  return vec4(textureColor.rgb * lightingFactor * albedo, 1.0);
}`
```

LOG :

```
Binding doesn't exist in [BindGroupLayout].
 - While validating that the entry-point's declaration for @group(0) @binding(3) matches [BindGroupLayout]
 - While validating the entry-point's compatibility for group 0 with [BindGroupLayout]
 - While validating fragment stage ([ShaderModule], entryPoint: ).
 - While validating fragment state.
 - While calling [Device].CreateRenderPipeline([RenderPipelineDescriptor]).
```

LAST LOG

```
The sample type in the shader is not compatible with the sample type of the layout.

None of the supported sample types (Float|UnfilterableFloat) of [Texture] match the expected sample types (Depth).
 - While validating entries[3] as a Texture.
Expected entry layout: { binding: 3, visibility: ShaderStage::(Vertex|Fragment), texture: { sampleType: TextureSampleType::Depth, viewDimension: TextureViewDimension::e2D, multisampled: 0 } }
 - While validating [BindGroupDescriptor] against [BindGroupLayout]
 - While calling [Device].CreateBindGroup([BindGroupDescriptor]).
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I follow warnings and fix types in bind layout call.
I found on https://www.w3.org/TR/webgpu/:

```
enum GPUSamplerBindingType {
    "filtering",
    "non-filtering",
    "comparison",
};
```

Also 'float' for texture.
Correct way looks :

```js
          {
            binding: 3,
            visibility: GPUShaderStage.VERTEX | GPUShaderStage.FRAGMENT,
            texture: {
              sampleType: 'float',
            },
          },
          {
            binding: 4,
            visibility: GPUShaderStage.VERTEX | GPUShaderStage.FRAGMENT,
            sampler: {
              type: 'filtering',
            },
          },
```

In shader i use `input.shadowPos.xy` like vec2 to satisfait textureSample.

```
let textureColor = textureSample(meshTexture, meshSampler, input.shadowPos.xy);
```

And works fine !